# How do I bind html inside ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

How do I dynamically bind the response data to the html generated inside ng-repeat?

Currently, only socialCount is being bound for all li's.

Here's my html:

```
<li ng-repeat="category in inbox.categories track by $index">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <div class="left-row" ng-click="inbox.showView(category)" target="_self">
                                        <div class="leftcolumn1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></div>
                                        <div class="leftcolumn2">{{category}}</div>
                                        <div class="leftcolumn3 email-time" ng-bind="inbox.messageCounts.socialCount"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </li>
```

and the response I get from the server is this:

```
{"socialCount":431,"promotionsCount":17843,"updatesCount":26997,"forumsCount":1780}
```

The js function:

Inbox.prototype.getMessageCounts = function(categories){

```
$http.get(
this.messageCountUrl + this.userGuid).success(function(data){
    this.messageCounts=data;
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: Questions not clear, What exactly is in inbox.categories? And what exactly you want to bind?

Comment: <div class="leftcolumn3 email-time" ng-bind="inbox.messageCounts.socialCount"></div> this piece of html needs to be bound. As you can see I only socialCount on every loop pass. I want forumsCount, updatesCount etc on each pass in a loop;

Comment: You don' have to worry about categories, it is working fine, It's just that the counts are not being bound.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, just have to do this.

```
<div class="leftcolumn3 email-time" ng-bind="inbox.messageCounts.{{category|lowercase}}Count"></div>
```